# For Loop no R - Regressão Linear

Tags: r

Olá, como estão?
Sou iniciante, e gostaria de tirar algumas dúvidas quanto a possibilidade de ser realizado, de maneira automática, regressões lineares.
Possuo uma base de dados com 520 observações (linhas) e 67 variáveis (colunas).
Gostaria de realizar regressões, como por exemplo, coluna 1 com coluna 2, coluna 1 com coluna 3 e assim sucessivamente. Também salvar, em uma nova base de dados, os resíduos de cada regressão.
Atualmente, faço de maneira manual no R, o que tende a causar uma demora no processo todo.

Ainda não possuo conhecimentos em for loop ou funções do tipo.
Se alguém puder dar uma luz, ajudaria muito.

```
reg <- lm(ativos$BBAS3~ativos$ITSA4)
residuos <- reg$residuals
summary(reg)

#Aqui é análise de estacionáriedade dos resíduos
estacionariedade_u <- ur.df(residuos, type = "none", selectlags = "AIC")
summary(estacionariedade_u)
```

Answer (score 4):

Correr várias regressões não é assim tão difícil quanto isso. O maior problema para quem está a começar a aprender R é nas funções `*apply` que são ciclos `for` disfarçados. Simplificam imenso as coisas quando se está à vontade com elas.

Primeiro vou criar um conjunto de dados, com 520 observações (linhas) e 7 variáveis (colunas). A resposta é a primeira coluna e as variáveis regressoras são as colunas seguintes.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Torna os resultados reprodutíveis

m <- 520
n <- 6
BBAS3 <- 1:m + rnorm(m, 0, 0.1)
ativos <- data.frame(BBAS3)
regr <- matrix(BBAS3 + rnorm(m*n), nrow = m)
colnames(regr) <- paste0("ITSA", 1:n)
ativos <- cbind(ativos, regr)
```

Agora o código do problema.
A função `lapply` aplica a todos os elementos do primeiro argumento a mesma função. Neste caso vou aplicar uma função sem nome, definida *ad-hoc*, por isso uma função dita *anónima*.

```
library(urca)

model_list <- lapply(ativos[-1], function(x) 
  lm(BBAS3 ~ x, data = ativos))
```

E pronto. Todas as regressões já correram, com as 6 colunas em questão a serem uma de cada vez passadas no argumento `x`. É por isso que retirei a primeira coluna, `ativos[-1]`, para ficar só com os regressores.

Veja o resultado da primeira regressão.

```
model_list[[1]]    # Uma maneira
model_list$ITSA1   # Equivalente
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = BBAS3 ~ x, data = ativos)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)            x  
#    0.09342      0.99991
```

Agora podemos usar esta lista de modelos para extrair o que quisermos, sempre com `lapply`.

```
resid_list <- lapply(model_list, residuals)
lapply(resid_list, summary)

estacionariedade_list <- lapply(resid_list, ur.df, type = "none", selectlags = "AIC")
estac_smry <- lapply(estacionariedade_list, summary)
```

Esta última lista, `estac_smry`, tem em cada elemento valores de interesse.

```
estac_pval <- lapply(estac_smry, function(x)
  x@testreg$coefficients[, 4])

estac_r.squared <- sapply(estac_smry, function(x)
  x@testreg$r.squared)

estac_adj.r.squared <- sapply(estac_smry, function(x)
  x@testreg$adj.r.squared)
```

As duas últimas instruções usam `sapply` para obter *vetores* como saída, o `lapply` dá sempre *listas*.

Comment: Rui Barradas, muito obrigado pela ajuda, sou extremamente grato. Realmente, simplificou muito. Vou focar mais na família apply.